# react.js вывод данных из массива объектов

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Есть вот такой код

```
import React from 'react';

const Answers = (props) => {
    let answers = [ 
        {"answer": "По программе первичного инструктажа для работников рабочих профессий"},
        {"answer": "По программе вводного инструктажа"},
        {"answer": "Программа не требуется"},
        {"question": "Виды инструктажей, проводимые для рабочих профессий:"}
    ]
      
      let answersElements = answers.map((answers) => {
        return (
          <button className ='btn-answer'>{answers.answer}</button>
        )
      });
    
      let randomAns = ((answersElements) => {
        return answersElements.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.51);
      });
      
      let answerRandom = randomAns(answersElements)
        return (
            <div>
               {answerRandom}
            </div>
          
    );
}

export default Answers;
```

Надо что б выводились только answer,  но выводиться 3 answer  и 1 пустая кнопка. Как это пофиксить, уже всю голову сломал...

Comment: а где у вас вообще что то выводится? не вижу render

Comment: ну а что вы хотите добиться? вы перебираете 4 элемента в `map`. 4 и выводятся, так как у последнего нет ключа `answer` то и нет значения. Если надо из массива получить только `answer` добавьте условие в `map` или воспользуйтесь фильтром.

Comment: @Alexandr это функциональный компонент, тут не нужен рендер

Comment: это 1 компонента она рендерится в другом месте. тут создается кнопка в которую вставлен ответ по идеи должно создаться 3 кнопки и все  но создается 3 кнопки с ответами и 1 пустая , если я правильно понимаю то он создает кнопки по количеству объектов в массиве и ему без разнице что написано дать только {answers.answer}

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov  спасибо попробую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answers.map((answers) => {
        return (
          <button className ='btn-answer'>{answers.answer}</button>
        )
      });
```

В этом коде вы проходите по массиву из 4 элементов, в три из них вы записываете answers.answer, а в 4ый идет unefined, так как нет такого свойства в 4ом элементе, вот и получаете на выходе 4 штуки, одна из которых пустая

Comment: да понял спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В итоге пришел к такому коду

```
import React from "react";

const Answers = (props) => {
  let questions= [
    {"id":1},
    {"answer": "По программе первичного инструктажа для работников рабочих профессий"},
    {"answer": "По программе вводного инструктажа"},
    {"answer": "Программа не требуется"},
    {"question": "Виды инструктажей, проводимые для рабочих профессий:"}]

  let answersElements = questions.map((questions) => {
    if (questions.answer)
      return <button className="btn-answer">{questions.answer}</button>;
  });

  let randomAns = (answersElements) => {
    return answersElements.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.51);
  };

  let answerRandom = randomAns(answersElements);
  return <div>{answerRandom}</div>;
};

export default Answers;
```

спасибо всем за помощь